# MariaDb 10 condition where id = '1' return same result where id ='1a'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I create table with id as primary key and int auto increment:
with this script

```
CREATE TABLE `devel_pos`.`menu` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO menu (title) VALUES ('Menu-1'),('Menu-2'),('Menu-3'),('Menu-4'),('Menu-5');
```

Then query some data where id = **'1'**

```
select * from menu where id = '1'
```

of course it return row with relevant data [1,'Menu-1']

Then query some data again where id = **'1a'**
it's return the same row with the first one [1, 'Menu-1']

```
select * from menu where id = '1b'
```

Why it's happen?

Comment: Why do *you* think it's happening?

Comment: change your statement with `select * from menu where id = 1;` because id is integer

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Functions and Operators  /  Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) (article for MariaDB not found)

> The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison
> operations:
>
> - If one or both arguments are NULL, the result of the comparison is NULL, except for the NULL-safe <=> equality comparison operator. For
>   NULL <=> NULL, the result is true. No conversion is needed.
> - If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are compared as strings.
> - If both arguments are integers, they are compared as integers.
> - Hexadecimal values are treated as binary strings if not compared to a number.
> - If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp
>   before the comparison is performed. This is done to be more
>   ODBC-friendly. This is not done for the arguments to IN(). To be safe,
>   always use complete datetime, date, or time strings when doing
>   comparisons. For example, to achieve best results when using BETWEEN
>   with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values
>   to the desired data type.
> - A single-row subquery from a table or tables is not considered a constant. For example, if a subquery returns an integer to be compared
>   to a DATETIME value, the comparison is done as two integers. The
>   integer is not converted to a temporal value. To compare the operands
>   as DATETIME values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the subquery
>   value to DATETIME.
> - If one of the arguments is a decimal value, comparison depends on the other argument. The arguments are compared as decimal values if
>   the other argument is a decimal or integer value, or as floating-point
>   values if the other argument is a floating-point value.
> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric
>   operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point numbers.

You compare integer column and string literal. Last rule is applied in this case. `'1'`, `'1a'` and `'1b'` are converted to numeric `1` in this case, and the row with `id=1` is selected.